# Evaluation R code in parallel using OMP and Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, openmp, rcpp

I have this code

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP Eval(string expr,Environment env){
    SEXP s = R_ParseEvalString(expr.c_str(),env);
    return s;
}

void ForEval(SEXP env){
    string code = "rnorm(10)";
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        SEXP res = PROTECT(Eval(code,env);
        // do something with res
        UNPROTECT(1);
    }
}
```

Now I want to convert ForEval function to parallel version but this code doesn't run. I believe I know why is wrong but is there any way to do it using SEXPs or Rcpp without using critical regions?

```
void ParallelForEval(SEXP env){
    string code = "rnorm(10)";

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        SEXP res = PROTECT(Eval(code,env);
        // do something with res
        UNPROTECT(1);
    }
}
```

I know this is correct but it is like the first version without parallel

```
void ParallelForEval2(SEXP env){
    string code = "rnorm(10)";

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            SEXP res = PROTECT(Eval(code,env);
            // do something with res
            UNPROTECT(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you dirk. I knew it that you can't do it but I hoped...

Comment: I have never asked to spend your time and more specific to re-explain something that has been answered many times. This question's answer does not exist in stackoverflow! I have searched a lot to come up to this question and even your duplicate answer does not answer it. Although, your first comment kind of answer it. I know it can't be done but I thought that might be an alternative to ```parallel::clusterEvalQ```. That's all. Thanks again.

Comment: I am done offering help here if moderators randomly delete comments.  Life's too short. Deleted all remaining prior comments.

Comment: According to *Writing R Extensions* calling any R API function from threaded code is "for experts only", which I interpret as "don't do it". You can make use of data structures from RcppArmadillo or RcppParallel, though. And if you need parallel random numbers, you should use [RNGs that are meant for that](https://www.daqana.org/dqrng/articles/parallel.html).